# Pytest select tests based on mark.parameterize value?

Tags: python, pytest

I see from [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html) that I can pick out tests based on their mark like so:

```
pytest -v -m webtest
```

Let's say I have a test decorated like so:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('platform,configuration', (
    pytest.param('win', 'release')
    pytest.param('win', 'debug')))
def test_Foo(self):
```

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
pytest -v -m parameterize.configuration.release
```

That way I run test_Foo with the parameter of 'release' but not the parameter of 'debug'.  Is there a way to do this?  I think I can do this by writing a wrapper test and then passing only the desired parameter down, but I want to avoid doing so because we already have a large number of tests parameterized as describe, and I want to avoid writing a large number of wrapper tests.

Comment: `-m` is for exact matching of markers so it's not applicable here, but you can use `-k` instead, for example `pytest -k win-release` or `pytest -k release`.

Comment: if that's not enough, you can always add your own logic that e.g. selects only tests having a parameter by name or name and value etc.

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need, thanks!  I'm still testing it but so far no nasty edge cases.

If you put it as a separate answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help! I've also added an example of adding custom filters as mentioned in the comment, should you be interested in further customization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `-k` for expression-based filtering:

```
$ pytest -k win-release
```

will run only tests containing `win-release` in their names. You can list all names without executing the tests by issuing

```
$ pytest --collect-only -q
```

Should an expression be not enough, you can always extend `pytest` by adding your custom filtering logic, for example by passing parameter name and value via command line args and selecting only tests that are parametrized accordingly:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--param-name', action='store',  help='parameter name')
    parser.addoption('--param-value', action='store',  help='parameter value')


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    param_name = config.getoption('--param-name')
    param_value = config.getoption('--param-value')
    if param_name and param_value:
        items[:] = [item for item in items
                    if hasattr(item, 'callspec')
                    and param_name in item.callspec.params
                    and item.callspec.params[param_name] == param_value]
```

Now you can e.g. call

```
$ pytest --param-name=platform --param-value=win
```

and only tests parametrized with `platform=win` will be executed.

Comment: `pytest --param-name=platform --param-name=win` should be `pytest --param-name=platform --param-value=win`

Comment: @SamuelVerschelde ah good catch! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the official [answer by hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52845103/7262247) is to create a special marker with [pytest-pilot](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-pilot/) and to apply it:

conftest.py:

```
from pytest_pilot import EasyMarker

mymark = EasyMarker('mymark', has_arg=False, mode='hard_filter')
```

test_so.py:

```
import pytest
from .conftest import mymark

@pytest.mark.parametrize('platform,configuration', (
        mymark.param('win', 'release'),
        pytest.param('win', 'debug')
))
def test_foo(platform, configuration):
    pass
```

You can now run `pytest --mymark`, it correctly runs only the test with the mark

```
test_so\test_so.py::test_foo[win-release] PASSED                         [ 50%]
test_so\test_so.py::test_foo[win-debug] SKIPPED                          [100%]
```

Of course it might not be relevant in all cases, as it requires code modification ; however for advanced filtering patterns, or if the filtering is here to stay and you wish to have some CLI shortcuts to perform it, it might be interesting. Note: I'm the author of this lib ;)